# Responsiveslide.js doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, slideshow, responsive-slides

I tried my code in http://jsfiddle.net/3J8vW/22/ and it worked perfectly, but when I tried it on my site it didnt work

Maybe I got an error in my js line

```
  (function ($) {
    $('#slider1').responsiveSlides();
  }(jQuery));
```

Website link /profil.html

Comment: You're loading jquery twice on the website: version 1.8.3 and 1.9.1

Comment: ok so I removed 1.8.3 but it still doesn't work

Comment: Load `responsiveslides.min.js` after `jquery.js`.

Comment: Can you post this as an answer so I can choose yours